# que significan estos parametros de funcion

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, parametros

```
def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> float:
```

estoy realizando ejercicios en leetcode, pero me encuentro con este tipo de parametros que no se que significan, ejemplo

que quiere decir los dos puntos después de la variable "nums1" o "nums2", que quiere decir List[int], quiere decir que introduzca una lista como parametro? o la flecha "-> float" después de los paréntesis

como rellenaría los parametros de esta función ? 
gracias.

Comment: Los **:** es el tipo del parámetro que debes enviar, en este caso es una Lista de enteros.

Comment: cuando intento esto la consola me dice que "List" no esta definida,, podrias mostrarme como llenar el parametro con un ejemplo ?

Comment: No es complicado, sería algo así: miLista = [1, 2, 3] y en la función enviarías miLista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintaxis que observas no es más que anotaciones o sugerencias de tipos. Python es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico como la gran mayoría de lenguajes interpretados, es decir, no es necesario indicar el tipo de una variable al declararla y además éste puede cambiar en cualquier momento. En realidad una variable no es más que un nombre que está asociado a cualquier objeto en memoria, dicho objeto (valor) tiene un tipo asociado (clase de la que es instancia), pero la variable en si misma no tiene un tipo asociado.

Esto hace que el lenguaje sea sumamente flexible al no tener que preocuparnos por definir los tipos de los objetos.

No obstante, el tipado dinámico también tiene sus inconvenientes, dejando fuera temas de eficiencia, en proyectos relativamente grandes, el tipado dinámico se nos puede ir de las manos y terminar con variables con tipo de datos que no deberían.

Para facilitar la tarea de depuración, test y también para permitir mayor legibilidad según que casos, a partir de Python 3.5 se implemento la posibilidad de realizar sugerencias de tipado en variables, argumentos, retornos de funciones/métodos, etc (aunque la idea ya estaba presente desde los inicios de Python 3). La implementación se apoya en el módulo [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) de la biblioteca estándar que básicamente define y permite el uso de múltiples tipos genéricos como es `List` para implementar las anotaciones de tipado. Además podemos ver una explicación muy extensa y detallada en PEP 484:

- [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Cabe aclarar que **Python sigue y seguirá siendo un lenguaje de tipado dinámico y fuerte**, la función de las anotaciones no es asignar un tipo a a las variables haciendo de Python un lenguaje de tipado estático, sino que su función es principalmente permitir a herramientas externas al propio intérprete evaluar el código y facilitar su depuraración. Una de estas herramientas es el linter [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/), aunque hay muchos más y algunos IDEs como PyCharm implementan los suyos propios.

La sintaxis más básica en lo referente a las anotaciones de funciones es la siguiente:

- El tipo de los argumentos se indica mediante una expresión opcional que sigue al nombre del parámetro y conformada por dos puntos `:` seguidos del tipo que debe tener dicho argumento.
- El tipo del retorno de la función se indica con `->` a continuación del paréntesis que contiene los argumentos seguido de una expresión Python válida.

En tu caso concreto el método `findMedianSortedArrays` recibe dos parámetros (además de `self`) que son `nums1` y `nums2`, ambos deben ser una **lista de enteros** (`List[int]`). Por otro lado el método debe retornar un `float`.

Es decir, debe ser llamado algo así:

```
resultado = instancia.findMedianSortedArrays([1, 2, 3], [7, 13, 17])
```

dónde resultado será un `float`.

`List` viene del ya mencionado módulo typing ([`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List)) y que define un tipo genérico de `list`, permitiendo como en este caso indicar el tipo de los items de la propia lista (`int` en este caso). Para que el código esté completo faltaría importar `List`:

```
from typing import List
```

Nada impide ignorar por completo las anotaciones, el intérprete (mientras no intentemos nada que no esté permitido) no comprobará para nada el tipo de los argumentos y el retorno, el siguiente código es perfectamente válido:

```
def suma(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

print(suma("Hola", "StackOverflow"))
```

A pesar de indicar que `a` y `b` deben ser enteros y que `suma` ha de retornar otro entero, el interprete no comprueba nada, como concatenar cadenas es posible simplemente lo hace y retorna una cadena....

Ahora bien, si analizamos el código con MyPy, este nos lanzará los esperados avisos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]