# ¿Cómo se puede validar el tipo de todos los elementos de una tupla?

Tags: python, tuplas

En Python podemos decir:

```
isinstance(3, int)
isinstance('hola', str)
```

Con ello vemos si `3` es un entero o 'hola' una cadena.

Sin embargo, a veces puede que tenga una tupla del tipo `(3, 'hola')`. En tal caso, me gustaría poder hacer algo así como:

```
isinstance((3, 'hola'), (int, str))
```

Es decir, validar si el primer elemento de la tupla es un entero y el segundo, una cadena. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que deberías cambiar el título a algo así: `¿ Cómo iterar a la vez sobre 2 listas ?`. A fin de cuentas, ese es el *meollo* del asunto.

Comment: @Trauma mmm discrepo, iterar sobre dos listas ya sé y no es lo que pregunto. Lo que me interesa saber es si se puede determinar el tipo de todos los elementos de una tupla.

Comment: Pues entonces no entiendo la pregunta. Para el tipo es `isinstance`, como dices. Y recorrer **1** tupla es trivial (hay *tropecientos* tutoriales en Google). La única pregunta válida que veo es como recorrer **a la vez** 2 tuplas O_o

Comment: Ah, vale. Ya lo pillo. Tu pregunta es sobre `isinstance`, no sobre recorrer listas.

Comment: @Trauma exacto :) saber si hay algún tipo de `isinstance()` que admita una tupla como primer parámetro y una tupla de tipos como segundo. Las buenas respuestas recibidas apuntan a que no, parece que las anotaciones de tipos pueden ser la solución más cercana

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal como se ha comentado en las anteriores respuestas, no hay una forma directa preconstruida en Python para validar todos los tipos de los items de un contenedor. La forma de hacerlos sería por tanto aplicar `isinstance` de forma iterativa.

El espectro de aplicación no es el mismo, pero dado que el objetivo es validar tipos voy a enfocar la respuesta a las [anotaciones de tipos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/335183/15089) introducidas en Python 3.5. Es común que las tuplas contengan datos de tipos heterogéneos por los que [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) da soporte directamente a este tipo de comprobación:

```
from typing import Tuple


def foo(tupla: Tuple[int, str]) -> None:
    pass


foo((3.4, 'hola'))
```

Si el código es analizado por MyPy o cualquier otro linter similar lanzado de forma explícita o incluido en el IDE de turno nos mostrará el consecuente aviso:

> $ python -m mypy test.py
>
> test.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Tuple[float, str]"; expected "Tuple[int, str]"
>   Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes jugar con las funciones "built-in" de Python: `zip`, `next`, `filter`, etc. https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html

Por ejemplo:

```
>>> objs = (3, "hola")
>>> my_types = (int, str)

>>> todo_ok = next(map(lambda p: False, filter(lambda pair: not isinstance(*pair), zip(objs, my_types))), True)
```

En este caso `todo_ok`es `True`

Otra opción sin usar `map` ni `filter`, pero de enfoque similar:

```
>>> todo_ok = next((False for pareja in zip(objs, my_types) if not isinstance(*pareja)), True)
```

La ventaja de usar `next()` es la eficiencia, cuando encuentra el primer objeto para el que no coincide el tipo retorna `False`, no recorre toda la tupla.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** He cambiado los `isinstance(pareja[0], pareja[1])` por una opción más elegante`isinstance(*pareja)`

Answer (score 3):

Si bien es una respuesta conceptualmente parecida a la de Trauma, tiene algunas diferencias. La idea es usar una comprensión de listas para hacer más compacto el código y la función `cycle()` para "ciclar" sobre las instancias a verificar, lo cual puede ser útil si tienes varios elementos para verificar de a grupos:

```
from itertools import cycle

tupla = (3, 'hola', 6, 7) 
instancias = (int, str)

val = [isinstance(v,i) for v, i in zip(tupla, cycle(instancias))]

print(val)
[True, True, True, False]

print(all(val))
False
```

Comment: Oh, vaya, te me has adelantado por unos segundos. Borraré la mia que venía a decir lo mismo pero sin `cycle()`

Comment: @abulafia, a veces pasa.. saludos

Comment: ¿Por qué el uso de `cycle()` aquí?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', a los efectos de tu pregunta es lo mismo que hacer `zip(tupla, instancias)`, sin embargo, puede ser útil en el caso que quieras, como en el ejemplo que dí, verificar un patrón de instancias, repetitivo en un conjunto mayor de valores.