# ¿Cómo usar una lista como parámetro de una función?

Tags: python, lista, parametros

Tengo que hacer un trabajo, es de principiante de programación y me esta dando varios problemas.

Primero tenia que hacer una funcion para pasar de grados celsius a farenheit y hasta ahí ningún problema con este código:

```
def gradosF(x):

    a = (x * 9/5) + 32

    return a
```

el problema llega en la segunda parte que te pide lo mismo pero usando una lista como parámetro de la función, he probado con `*args`:

```
def convert_all(*grados):

    for grado in grados:
          a =  (grados * 9/5) + int(32)

    return a
```

me salta este error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'

no se que hacer, por favor seria de gran ayuda que me explicaseis el tema de usar una lista como parámetro de una función.

Answer (score 4):

La sintaxis `*args`  permite pasar un número indeterminado de parámetros posicionales a la función, los cuales se empaquetan en una tupla. `args` es solo una convención, puedes usar cualquier identificador válido como haces en tu caso. El problema con tu función es que haces:

```
a =  (grados * 9/5) + int(32)
```

dónde `grados` es una tupla como se ha comentado e intentas multiplicarla por un entero, lo cual no es posible. Python no implementa operaciones vectorizadas en sus contenedores estándar, como hace NumPy.

Debes iterar sobre la tupla, realizar la operación por cada elemento y añadirlo a una lista temporal. Al final, retornas la lista:

```
def convert_all(*grados):
    grados_farenheit = []
    for grado in grados:
          grados_farenheit.append(grado * 9 / 5 + 32)
    return grados_farenheit
```

o usando directamente listas por compresión:

```
def convert_all(*grados):
    return [grado * 9 / 5 + 32 for grado in grados]
```

> ```
> >>> print(convert_all(5, 13, 19))
> [41.0, 55.4, 66.2]
>
> >>> grados = [17, 23, 43]
> >>> print(convert_all(*grados))
> [62.6, 73.4, 109.4]
> ```

Ahora bien, si quiere que la función reciba realmente una lista con los grados a convertir, simplemente debes quitar el `*`:

```
def convert_all(grados):
    return [grado * 9 / 5 + 32.0 for grado in grados]
```

> ```
> >>> grados = [13, 15, 16]
> >>> print(convert_all(grados))
> [55.4, 59.0, 60.8]
> ```

La conversión explícita a `int` de `32` es innecesaria, `32` es un literal de `int`.

Podemos usar [anotaciones de tipos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/335204/15089) para dejar más cláro que espera recibir la función y que retorna:

```
from typing import List, Union

def convert_all(grados: List[Union[int, float]]) -> List[float]:
    return [grado * 9 / 5 + 32.0 for grado in grados]
```